# AndroidX transition and Cordova, what are the risks/benefits?

Tags: cordova, plugins, migration, androidx

**Here's my story:** I've migrated my app to AndroidX because I needed some new features from a library I found online.

**Problem:** I'm currently running into some issues because I now need to develop a plugin for Cordova that implements a part of that app.

I generated a .arr file with my library & tried to make a Cordova plugin which acts as a interface to use the library. But when I try to use `cordova-plugin-camera` with my plugin, which uses AndroidX, I get errors: duplicate imports because `cordova-plugin-camera` uses the support library.

**Solution:** I've removed the dependencies to AndroidX & replaced them with the old support library.

**Question:** Is it a good idea to switch to AndroidX right now or am I better off keeping the support library ? Did I implement something wrong ? What did you choose for your projects ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've created a couple of utility plugins to assist with AndroidX migration in Cordova Android projects:

- [cordova-plugin-androidx](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx) will persistently configure a Cordova Android platform project to use AndroidX.
- [cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter) migrates any references to the legacy Support Library in a Cordova Android platform project to use the AndroidX equivalent names.

I created these as a generic solution for AndroidX support in my existing plugins which reference the Android Support Library, e.g. [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) against which [AndroidX support issues has been raised](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/350).

This means that by installing both of these plugins in a Cordova project that already contains plugins which reference either the legacy Support Library names and/or the AndroidX names, the build will now succeed.

For example, try this test case:

```
cordova create test && cd test
cordova platform add android@8
cordova build android
    => build succeeds
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic@5
cordova build android
    => build succeeds
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
cordova build android
    => build fails
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
cordova build android
    => build succeeds
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but it seems like a good alternative. Thanks for the infos

Comment: Hi, it seems this does not work when applied through Android Studio. I have tried using Android Studio to do this, now all the Libraries say in Build Output in AS: error: package androidx.core.content does not exist

Comment: really helpfull, just one question, why cordova official does not solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Just read that :
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/29/cordova-android-9.0.0.html

To be sure :

- Clear your gradle cache directory (in home/.gradle/caches)
- Remove and add the android platform
- Check your requirement following the above article ones

Then :

Add the following in your config.xml :

```
<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinEnabled" value="true" />
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinCodeStyle" value="official" />
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinVersion" value="1.3.50" />
```

(AndroidXEnabled preference add jetifyer and androidX in the gradle.properties)

- Add the https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter plugin.
- Then prepare the android platform

And your build should now works

---

Btw @DaveAlden the https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx is messing up the gradle.properties file by adding multiples times the enable-jetifier and enableAndroidX rules instead of juste changing the bool values

Comment: Thank you for the complementary informations. I do not work on this project anymore so unfortunately I won't be able to try your solution.